# Enemy in game wont fall after shooting *lines 170-180 *

Tags: python, pygame

My code is here:

```
import pygame, io  # Can also list other libraries to import: sys, time, io, random, ...
from pygame.locals import *
from urllib.request import urlopen


# *** DEFINE FUNCTIONS HERE ***

def drawPlayer(surface, x, y, r):
    pygame.draw.polygon(surface, SILVER, (((x - 25), (y + 25)), (x, y), ((x + 25), (y + 25))))
    pygame.draw.circle(surface, BLACK, (x, (y + 10)), (r - 5))
    if shieldOn == True:
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, ORANGE, (x, (y + 15)), (25), 3)
    if wallOn == True:
        pygame.draw.line(surface, YELLOW, ((x - 10), (y - 5)), ((x - 10), (y - 5)), 3)


def drawEnemy(surface, enemyRect):
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, TEAL, (enemyRect.x, enemyRect.y, enemyRect.width, enemyRect.height))


pygame.init()

# Set up the window and Surface object

FPS = 30  # frames per second setting
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init()

# set up the window
winWid = 500
winHGT = 400
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((winWid, winHGT))

# set up the colors
AQUA = (0, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)
GREEN = (0, 128, 0)
MAROON = (128, 0, 0)
NAVY_BLUE = (0, 0, 128)
LIGHT_BLUE = (0, 0, 196)
OLIVE = (128, 128, 0)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
SILVER = (192, 192, 192)
TEAL = (0, 128, 128)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BROWN = (128, 64, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 140, 0)

# Set up image for background
image_url = "https://codehs.com/uploads/f18f32b18c132ff9a65bc2c0959f685a"
image_str = urlopen(image_url).read()
image_file = io.BytesIO(image_str)
backgroundImg = pygame.image.load(image_file)

# Set up variables for the player
playerX = int(winWid / 2)
playerY = 350

# Set up variables for the enemy
enemyRects = []
enemyX = 5
enemyY = 30
enemyDiameter = 20
numSegments = 20
enemyMoveX = []
enemyMoveY = []
enemyAlive = []

BEGIN = 0
PLAY = 1
GAMEOVER = 2
gameState = BEGIN

for i in range(numSegments):
    enemyAlive.append(True)

numShots = 0
maxShots = 4
laserRects = []
for i in range(maxShots):
    laserRects.append(pygame.Rect(-5, -10, 5, 10))

for e in range(numSegments):
    enemyRects.append(pygame.Rect(enemyX + (e * (enemyDiameter + 4)), enemyY, enemyDiameter, enemyDiameter))
    enemyMoveX.append(2)
    enemyMoveY.append(0)

# Shield Variables

shieldOn = False
shieldTimer = 90

wallOn = False

score = 0
totalNumOfShots = 0
scoreFont = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 14)
centerX = 100
centerY = 10
midX = 250
midY = 200

# run the game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            playerX = pos[0]

        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if gameState == BEGIN:
                    gameState = PLAY
                if (laserRects[numShots].bottom < 0):
                    laserRects[numShots].left = playerX - 2
                    laserRects[numShots].top = playerY
                    numShots += 1
                    totalNumOfShots += 1
                    if (numShots >= 4):
                        numShots = 0

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                shieldOn = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                wallOn = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                wallOn = False

    # Draw the image to the background
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(backgroundImg, (0, 0))

    if gameState == BEGIN:
        beginSurface = scoreFont.render("Click to Start", False, BLUE)   # Colors are for text and background. Leave background blank and change the boolean to False if you want no background.
        # Create a Rect object from the Surface object 
        beginRect = beginSurface.get_rect()
        # Set the position of the Rect object 
        beginRect.center = (midX, midY)
        # Draw the text Surface object onto the main Surface object 
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(beginSurface, beginRect)

    elif gameState == PLAY:
        # Move each segment of the enemy
        for i in range(len(enemyRects)):
            if (enemyRects[i].left < 0 or enemyRects[i].right > winWid):
                enemyMoveX[i] *= -1
                enemyMoveY[i] = enemyDiameter - 2

            enemyRects[i] = enemyRects[i].move(enemyMoveX[i], enemyMoveY[i])
            enemyMoveY[i] = 0

        for i in range(maxShots):
            laserRects[i] = laserRects[i].move(0, -5)
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, laserRects[i])

        for i in range(len(laserRects)):
            for j in range(len(enemyRects)):
                if laserRects[i].colliderect(enemyRects[j]) and enemyAlive[j] == True:
                    enemyMoveX[j] = 0
                    enemyMoveY[j] = 1
                    if enemyRects[i].bottom == 400:
                        enemyAlive[j] = False
                    laserRects[i].bottom = -1
                    score += 5

            # Draw the enemy
            for j in range(len(enemyRects)):
                if enemyAlive[j] == True:
                    drawEnemy(DISPLAYSURF, enemyRects[j])

            for j in range(len(enemyRects)):
                if enemyAlive == False:
                    gameState = gameOver

            # Draw the player
            drawPlayer(DISPLAYSURF, playerX, playerY, 10)

            if shieldOn == True:
                shieldTimer -= 1
                if shieldTimer <= 0:
                    shieldOn = False
                    shieldTimer = 90


        textSurface = scoreFont.render("Score: " + str(score) + "   -   Total Shots:" + str(totalNumOfShots), False, WHITE)   # Colors are for text and background. Leave background blank and change the boolean to False if you want no background.
        # Create a Rect object from the Surface object 
        textRect = textSurface.get_rect()
        # Set the position of the Rect object 
        textRect.center = (centerX, centerY)
        # Draw the text Surface object onto the main Surface object 
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurface, textRect)

    elif gameState == GAMEOVER:
        beginSurface = scoreFont.render("GAME"/"OVER", False, RED)  

        beginRect = textSurface.get_rect()

        beginRect.center = (midX, midY)

        DISPLAYSURF.blit(beginSurface, begintRect)

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

At this part

```
        for i in range(len(laserRects)):
            for j in range(len(enemyRects)):
                if laserRects[i].colliderect(enemyRects[j]) and enemyAlive[j] == True:
                    enemyMoveX[j] = 0
                    enemyMoveY[j] = 1
                    if enemyRects[i].bottom == 400:
                        enemyAlive[j] = False
                    laserRects[i].bottom = -1
                    score += 5
```

The enemies should (or are supposed to) fall after being shot, having a chance to collide and kill the player (not there yet) and currently, when shot the enemies stop moving.

the instructions state:

To make this happen,

- When the enemy is hit with a laser, the current index in the list for
  the y movement of the enemy is set to a value that is not 0 so it
  moves down the screen.
- Also, the current index in the list for the y
  movement of the enemy is set to 1 or -1 depending on which way it is
  moving (The trick here is to let it equal itself divided by the
  absolute value of itself) .
- Up where you move the enemy segments, you
  set the y movement back to 0 after it hits the wall. Only do this if
  the current enemy segment is alive.
- You will also need to get rid of
  the if statement that only draws the enemy if it is alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ian.  Cool game.

Your problem is in the logic of y-movement and "dead aliens".  In your move block, you are constantly resetting the y movement to zero.  If the alien is dead, you don't want to do that.  Your aliens only "die" when they get to the ground...so they never die... !  I changed a little of your code to kill the alien as soon as collision happens and use that logic for the movement and I think this will put you back on track!  Snippet with modifications in it:

```
elif gameState == PLAY:
    # Move each segment of the enemy
    for i in range(len(enemyRects)):
        if (enemyRects[i].left < 0 or enemyRects[i].right > winWid):
            enemyMoveX[i] *= -1
            enemyMoveY[i] = enemyDiameter - 2

        enemyRects[i] = enemyRects[i].move(enemyMoveX[i], enemyMoveY[i])
        # check if alive.  If dead, we want to keep it moving down...
        if enemyAlive[i] : 
            enemyMoveY[i] = 0

    for i in range(maxShots):
        laserRects[i] = laserRects[i].move(0, -5)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, laserRects[i])

    for i in range(len(laserRects)):
        for j in range(len(enemyRects)):
            if laserRects[i].colliderect(enemyRects[j]) and enemyAlive[j] == True:
                # set enemy to dead here, not when it hits ground.
                enemyAlive[j] = False
                enemyMoveX[j] = 0
                enemyMoveY[j] = 15   # bumped up speed
                # need to figure out what to do with this part... I dunno
                if enemyRects[i].bottom == 400:
                    enemyAlive[j] = False
                laserRects[i].bottom = -1
                score += 5

        # Draw the enemy
        for j in range(len(enemyRects)):
            #if enemyAlive[j] == True:    <-- removed.  we draw everything now.
            drawEnemy(DISPLAYSURF, enemyRects[j])
```

Comment: When I try to add the code, I cant seem to get it in without an error 

Edit Just figured it out, thank you!